# How can I run a function / action every period of time (once an hour)?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, autocmd, functions, date-and-time

I want to run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588531/vim-set-color-theme-based-off-time-of-day

So something like:

```
if strftime("%H") < 12
  set background=light
else
  set background=dark
endif
```

But for this to be invoked every hour, rather than only once when opening vim. Does vim or neovim support running a periodic action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`timer_start()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#timer_start%28%29) to set "timers" to run a function every *n* milliseconds. For example:

```
fun! s:set_bg(timer_id)
    let &background = (strftime('%H') < 12 ? 'light' : 'dark')
endfun
call timer_start(1000 * 60, function('s:set_bg'), {'repeat': -1})
call s:set_bg(0)  " Run on startup
```

This will run `s:set_bg()` every 1 minute (60,000 milliseconds), and by setting `repeat` to `-1` it will run indefinitely (rather than just once).

As far as I've been able to see in my (short) testing, this doesn't cause any side-effects such as slow-downs or flickering. You can consider changing the logic to set `background` only if it differs from the current value if it does (but looks like Vim is smart enough on its own).

---

Note that resetting the colour scheme (as you did in your own answer), *does* cause some flicking for me; you can get the current scheme name with `g:colors_name`, and use something like this to change it only when needed:

```
fun! s:set_bg(timer_id)
        let l:hour = strftime('%H')

        if l:hour < 18 && g:colors_name isnot# 'zellner'
                set background=light
                colorscheme zellner
        elseif l:hour > 18 && g:colors_name isnot# 'nightfly'
                set background=dark
                colorscheme nightfly
        endif
endfun
```

You can probably make this a bit shorter if you want, but should get the idea.

If you want to be able to disable the switching at runtime, then return the timer ID from `timer_start()` and call `timer_stop()` on it.

---

Support for timers was added in Vim 7.4.1578 (March 2016), and some *very* old installations may not have it (this is also why the SO question you link doesn't mention it, as that was asked before this feature existed).

Comment: Current colorscheme should be available in `g:colors` or some such similar variable (I forget the exact name). Good to see you hanging around some :)

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble; have to do something when you're stuck inside like much of the planet :-( And yeah, looks like it's in `g:colors_name`.

Comment: [@Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/martin-tournoij) I have created a [post on dev.to](https://dev.to/voyeg3r/set-your-vim-colorscheme-and-background-based-on-hour-hoj) about changing the background and I think using the reminder of division helps us to create a shorter code. By the way, your solution with timers will be added there, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround one can instead target the common `FocusLost` / `FocusGained` events.

```
function DynamicColorThemeSwitch()
  if strftime("%H") < 18
    set background=light
    colorscheme zellner
  else
    set background=dark
    colorscheme nightfly
  endif
endfunction

autocmd FocusLost,FocusGained * call DynamicColorThemeSwitch()
call DynamicColorThemeSwitch()
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it if you don't have the `+timers` feature in your Vim. Perhaps adding the `CursorHold` event might be a good idea as well? There are quite a few conditions where the `Focus*` events aren't triggered (not leaving the Vim window for a while, but also in various terminal emulators)